# Running glmnet with rpy2 on sparse design matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, rpy2, glmnet

I have a python snippet which works just fine to run GLMNET on `np.array` X and y. However, when X is a column sparse matrix from scipy, the code fails as rpy2 is not able to convert X. Am I making an obvious mistake?

A MCVE is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from rpy2 import robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = sparse.rand(5, 20, density=0.1)
    y = np.random.randn(5)
    numpy2ri.activate()
    pandas2ri.activate()

    utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
    utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) 
    if not rpackages.isinstalled('glmnet'):
        utils.install_packages("glmnet")
    glmnet = rpackages.importr('glmnet')

    glmnet = robjects.r['glmnet']
    glmnet_fit = glmnet(X, y, intercept=False, standardize=False)
```

And when I run it I get a `NotImplementedError`:

```
Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '<class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>'
```

Could I provide X in a different way? I'd be surprised if rpy2 could not handle sparse matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a sparse matrix with rpy2 as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from scipy import sparse

X = sparse.rand(5, 20, density=0.1).tocoo()
r_Matrix = importr("Matrix")
r_Matrix.sparseMatrix(
    i=ro.IntVector(X.row + 1),
    j=ro.IntVector(X.col + 1),
    x=ro.FloatVector(X.data),
    dims=ro.IntVector(X.shape))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed no converter Python -> R for your object type included in rpy2. Your Python object is not a conventional arrays but a sparse matrix as you note it (`scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix` to be specific), implemented as one of the numerical extensions available for numpy. As `numpy` itself is not even required to use `rpy2` the support for extension of numpy is rather sparse, at the notable exception of `pandas` since data tables are ubiquitous.

You may want to write your own converter from `css_matrix` to `gcCMatrix` in the R package `Matrix` (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dgCMatrix-class.html) as the package `glmnet` appears to be able to handle them.

Writing a custom converter will require how to map or copy the content of the Python object to its chosen R counterpart, but once done plugging the code into rpy2 should be quite easy:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/generated_rst/s4class.html#custom-conversion

Consider opening an issue as a "feature request" on the rpy2 issue tracker, and reporting progress and outcome, with the hope to see this turn into a pull request complete with unit tests

Answer (score 1):

Also a quick solution that might work would be to save the sparse matrix file temporarily.

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import warnings
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeWarning
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri as numpy2ri
from scipy.io import mmwrite
mmwrite('temp.mtx',matrix)
ro.r('X <- readMM("temp.mtx")')
```

I would be very interested though, if someone comes with a custom converter for avoiding that copy to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The python package **anndata2ri** has functions for converting scipy sparse matrices to R and vice versa.

```
import anndata2ri
anndata2ri.activate()
r_sparse_mat = anndata2ri.scipy2ri.py2rpy(py_sparse_mat)
```